# После переустановки приложения я не получаю купленный товар ! Что не так?

Tags: java, android

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        mBillingClient();
    }

    private Map<String, SkuDetails> mSkuDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();
    private String mSkuId1 = "mSkuId1";
    private String mSkuId2 = "mSkuId2";
    private BillingClient mBillingClient;

    public void mBillingClient() {
        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
                if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && purchases != null) {
                    //сюда мы попадем когда будет осуществлена покупка

                    List<Purchase> purchasesList = queryPurchases();
                    for (int i = 0; i < purchasesList.size(); i++) {
                        String purchaseId = purchasesList.get(i).getSku();
                        if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId1, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete();
                        }

                        if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId2, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete2();
                        }}

                }

            }
        }).build();
        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
                if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    //здесь мы можем запросить информацию о товарах и покупках
                    querySkuDetails();
                    List<Purchase> purchasesList = queryPurchases();
                    for (int i = 0; i < purchasesList.size(); i++) {
                        String purchaseId = purchasesList.get(i).getSku();

                        if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId1, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete();
                        }

                        if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId2, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete2();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                //сюда мы попадем если что-то пойдет не так
            }
        });
    }



    private void querySkuDetails() {
        SkuDetailsParams.Builder skuDetailsParamsBuilder = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
        skuList.add(mSkuId1);
        skuList.add(mSkuId2);
        skuDetailsParamsBuilder.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParamsBuilder.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                if (responseCode == 0) {
                    for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                        mSkuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void Start(View view) {
        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(mSkuDetailsMap.get(mSkuId1))
                .build();
        mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
    }

    public void Start2(View view) {
        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(mSkuDetailsMap.get(mSkuId2))
                .build();
        mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
    }


    public void payComplete() {

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean( "loadUr1" , true);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void payComplete2() {

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean( "loadUr2" , true);
        editor.apply();
    }


    private List<Purchase> queryPurchases() {
        Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        return purchasesResult.getPurchasesList();
    }
```

Comment: Все делается без 2. Переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: У меня есть две кнопки (и я хочу , чтобы  по нажатию на одну кнопку  я покупал один товар - и получал  как результат покупки код написанный для первой кнопки  ) Также и соответственно для другой . А тут получается что (после любой покупки я буду переходить в  payComplete(); )  вот что получается если я куплю по второй кнопке я получу код с первой

Comment: к вам приходит List<Purchase> purchases, там и проверяйте что куплено purchase.getSku().equals( "ЧТО_КУПЛЕНО" )

Comment: if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && purchases != null) {
                    //сюда мы попадем когда будет осуществлена покупка
                
purchase.getSku().equals( "ЧТО_КУПЛЕНО" ) 
                } ?

Comment: @Style-7  посмотрите я правильно понял я добавил правку к вопросу в самом конце!

Comment: Ну да. Для упрощения используйте цикл for( Purchase purchase : purchases )

Answer (score 1):

Перешел из комментариев сюда. Вы забыли очень важный момент. без которого все покупки возвратятся пользователю через трое суток. Все покупки нужно подтверждать(!).
Потом еще нужно обязательно обращать внимание на статус платежа - он может быть еще незавершенный: просим пользователя зайти и проверить попозже (!).

```
for( Purchase purchase : purchases ){
   if( purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED ){

      if( !purchase.isAcknowledged() ){ //не подтверждены
           billing_client.acknowledgePurchase(...) //подтверждаем
      }
   }else if( purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING ){
   }
}
```

Comment: А где  все покупки нужно подтверждать ?(В гугл консоле )

Comment: В какое место нужно вставлять данный код ^

Comment: Style-7 Можете посмотреть после переустановки приложения я не получаю купленного   товара (что уже не так я полностью  изменю первоначальное описание вопроса )

Comment: вам лучше изучить оф. документацию https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview, я не могу все рассказать тут, нужно смотреть "логи", вариантов масса

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: Style-7  Последний вопрос (мне все это нужно запустить в другом классе - так не работает может что посоветуете ) Main2Activity a = new Main2Activity();
        a.mBillingClient();

Comment: посоветую все покупки совершать в отдельной активности

Comment: тут кстати можно ответы принимать